# docker-compose only running my mongodb server but not running my js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to using docker. I'm developing a simple form that submits data inputted by a user into a mongodb database and redirects him/her to a thank you html page.
It's working perfectly on my localhost but when I dockerize it, it doesn't work.
Thing is, my code works perfectly on Mac but not on Windows OS.
Any help will be appreciated.

Here's my js code:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../public'));
app.get('/', (req,res)=> file = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/clientlogin.html').pipe(res));
app.get('/thanks', (req,res)=> file = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/formthanks.html').pipe(res));
app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req,res){
    var firstname = req.body.firstname;
    var lastname = req.body.lastname;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var phonenumber = req.body.phonenumber;
    var pass = req.body.password;

// Use connect method to connect to the server
var url = "mongodb://mongo:27017/clientdb";
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var obj = {
        'FirstName': firstname,
        'LastName': lastname,
        'Email': email,
        'PhoneNumber': phonenumber,
        'Pass': pass
    };
    db.collection("myclients").insertOne(obj, function(err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("1 client registered!");
      db.close();
    });
    res.redirect('/thanks');
});

});
app.listen(8081, function(){
    console.log("Listening on port 8081");
});
```

My package.json code

```html
{
  "name": "loginpage",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "login page",
  "main": "signupmongo.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node signupmongo.js"
  },
  "author": "David",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.33",
    "mongoose": "^4.13.4"
  }
}
```

My dockerfile

```html
FROM node:argon
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8081
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My docker-compose.yml file

```html
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Here's the command line interface where the code appears to stop running.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo3Fi.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to link the mongo container in your app container. Use the links feature for this
Example:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    links:
      - mongo
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Tamas . Effected the changes you recommended, still no difference. I have appended a snapshot of where the code appears to stop running in the question.  I'm using Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4

Comment: I have added a url to a snapshot of the command line interface when the code appears to stop running at the base of my question. It doesn't bring up an error but it's just not executing my js file.